# Semi-transparent menu item on hover to background image

Tags: html, css

is there any way to make menu item hover transparent to background image?
As you can see, image in background is set with background-size cover option and background can scale in different screen size.

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <p></p>
  <div class="menu-container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.header{
  background: url('http://de.fwsx.co/mbergs/images/home-header.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
}  

p:first-child,
p:last-child {
  height: 50px;
}

div.menu-container {
  background: #fff;
}

div.menu-container ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

div.menu-container ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

div.menu-container ul li a:hover {
  background: rgba(64,161,47, 0.6);
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qwLp9f9y/1/

Edit: Full width menu container must stay solid white.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you want https://jsfiddle.net/qwLp9f9y/2/

Comment: @Alorika It sure it isnt

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/qwLp9f9y/3/

Comment: @CodeiSir: Semi-transparent background like this : https://jsfiddle.net/qwLp9f9y/4/

Comment: Full width menu container must stay solid white.

Comment: @Janiis does my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the background from the container (only way to solve this in a cross browser way).

To be able to reproduce visually the white background on the container, I have added small shadows to the li's  (to fill the gap between one and the next) and a before pseudo element on the first one, and the last one, to cover the margins on both sides

```css
div.header{
  background: url('http://de.fwsx.co/mbergs/images/home-header.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
}  

p:first-child,
p:last-child {
  height: 50px;
}


div.menu-container ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px white;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-container li:first-child:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  right: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
.menu-container li:last-child:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
div.menu-container ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

div.menu-container li:hover {
  background: rgba(64,161,47, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  
  <p>

  </p>
  
  <div class="menu-container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <p>

  </p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Happy that it helped !

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to switch to a table Layout to acheive this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lv0rkhun/1/

I can't think of a way doing it with ul/li Elements.

```
  <table class="menu-container" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td><div></div></td>
      <td><a href="#" title="">Menu 1</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" title="">Menu 2</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" title="">Menu 3</a></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need this with ul/li layout. I tried to add ::before and ::after  elements, but without success.

Comment: @Janiis May I ask why you need it to be ul/li? Maybe we can solve this, bcause without table it's going to be hard.

Comment: Thanks. I need it to be responsive menu also, so the best option is table-less layout.

Comment: Here is live/demo menu and layout: http://de.fwsx.co/mbergs/ and as you can see it is nested menu also, so there is no option for table layout.

Comment: I invest time and then you come and say you need this and that in addition.. you should say from the beginning what you need

Comment: Sorry, about that. I'm new to this forum. I will approve your answer as correct, if there will be no more responses as your solution works for the given code in question.